# Is it safe to store socket.io sockets in a server object?

Tags: node.js, redux, socket.io

This might be a dumb question, but I am trying to explain it as simply as I can.

So I have been using axios to retrieve data from my server to my react app (redux)
Since I use socket.io in my app a lot, I thought I could make the authentication use that as well, so I don't have to use axios and socket.io concurrently. I have been using PassportJS for authentication, but I can't wrap my head around how the socket.io passport packages I found on npm work.

I am using [this](https://github.com/itaylor/redux-socket.io) socket.io-redux middleware to fire reducers on socket.io events. With this, I can dispatch actions that then get sent to the server, and from the server I can fire the reducers I want, in order to change the state.

Here is my store.js

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import createSocketIoMiddleware from 'redux-socket.io';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
const socketIoMiddleware = createSocketIoMiddleware(socket, "io/");


const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk, socketIoMiddleware];

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    )
);

// store.dispatch({type:'server/hello', data:'Hello!'});

export default store
```

Using this method a socket is created for every client upon connecting to the website. I created a Store class on the server side as well, with the the login/logout methods like so (these keep track of the clients and the users associated with them):

```js
class Store
{
    constructor(){
        this.loggedInUsers = [];
    }

    loginUser(userID, socketID){
        console.log('login', userID, socket.id);
        
        const index = this.loggedInUsers.find(u => u.socketID !== socket.id && u.userID === userID);
        if(index >= 0){
            this.logoutUser(this.loggedInUsers[index].socketID);
        }
        
        this.loggedInUsers = [
            ...this.loggedInUsers, 
            {
                userID: userID,
                socketID: socket.id,
            }
        ];
    }

    logoutUser(socketID){
        console.log('logout', socketID);
        const index = this.loggedInUsers.find(u => u.socketID === socketID);
        if(index >= 0){
            this.loggedInUsers = [...this.loggedInUsers.slice(0, index), ...this.loggedInUsers.slice(index+1)];
        }
    }
}

module.exports.store = new Store();
```

On login a socket.io event is emmitted to the server, then on a successful login the socket gets stored in a loggedInUsers object that holds the user IDs and the sockets associated with them, then fires a reducer to store the authenticated state in my store. On logout, the user with the socket given gets removed from the object.

Now I am wondering if this is even safe to do or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the exact same thing in a previous project that I worked, saved in an array the mongo and socket id-s of each user.

Think of it this way, how much memory will one of these objects take, about 50 bytes maybe? 60? So technically you can have ~10 million of these in memory, assuming with a maximum usage of 500 MB of memory. The Node maximum memory limit goes from 700MB to 1.4GB between 32 and 64 bit systems, so with 10 million socket instances (which are not the same as 10 million simultaneous users since a user can have more than one tab open, and one socket is created for each tab/instance) you should be safe, since Node itself is assumed to not be used for intensive operations.

Now these are the limits, and in the end, you still can stretch beyond this limit by using some Redis or Memcache to be sort of in between memory and storage speed, and since I don't know your scenario I assume that you are pretty safe in terms of leaks if you correctly cleanup the logged out users.